# Group operation

Tags: group-theory

I have learnt [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3063201/some-more-basics-on-group-operation/3063228#3063228) that, given a group $G$ and a subgroup $H \le G$, if we denote by $f$ the group operation and by $\complement_GH$ the complement of $H$ in $G$, we have that $f(\complement_GH \times \complement_GH)=G$ whenever $[G:H]>2$. Let's now suppose $G$ *finite* and $[G:H]>2$. How many pairs $(g,g') \in \complement_GH \times \complement_GH$ are there such that $gg'^{-1} \in H$ ?

Comment: The number is $\left|H\right|^2 \left(\left[G:H\right] - 1\right)$. Hint for the proof: Argue that $g\left(g^{\prime}\right)^{-1} \in H$ is equivalent to $Hg = Hg^{\prime}$, i.e., equivalent to $g$ and $g^{\prime}$ lying in the same $Hx$-coset of $H$ in $G$. Now, how many cosets are there, and for each coset, how many pairs of elements both belong to this coset?

Comment: I rephrase/deploy your hint to see if I got it: $\complement_GH$ is made of $[G:H]-1$ cosets; *within* each of them, we can built up $|H|^2$ products; so there are $|H|^2([G:H]-1)$ pairs $(g,g') \in \complement_GH \times \complement_GH$ such that $Hg=Hg'$ $(\Leftrightarrow gg'^{-1} \in H$). Does it fit?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.