# Does there exist a group $G$ with a proper subgroup $K$ in which for all $a, b \in G - K$ such that $ab \neq e$, we have $ab \in G - K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, arithmetic, binary-operations

I am currently studying group theory and I asked myself various questions, though I was able to solve almost all of them, I could not answer the following one:

Does there exist a group $G$ with a proper subgroup $K$ in which for all $a, b \in G - K$ such that $ab \neq e$, we have $ab \in G - K$?

Please help me, I am completely stuck!

Comment: This question is new to me.  It would be a shame to close it; however, it needs a little more context. Please [edit] the question to include more details.

Comment: No, it seems it doesn't exist: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3063228/1092170

Comment: Please would you elaborate, @Devo?

Comment: As per the linked answer, while $a$ and $b$ go throughout $G\setminus H$, $ab$ goes throughout $G$ if $[G:H]>2$, and throughout $H$ if $[G:H]=2$, @Shaun.

Comment: So, some $ab$ (if not all, as in the $[G:H]=2$ case) falls outside $G\setminus H$.

Comment: I'll have to think about that, but thank you, @Devo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can only hold if $K$ is trivial. Indeed, if $K$ is nontrivial, $k\in K$ with $k\neq e$, and $a\notin K$, then $a,a^{-1}k$ are both not in $K$, but $e\neq k = a(a^{-1}k) \in K$.

And if $K$ is trivial, this necessarily holds.